# Cannot rescale video in ffmpeg, gives error

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg.exe -stats -threads 28 -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -extra_hw_frames 6 -i "<<InputFileName>>" -f mp4 -movflags +faststart -t 3600 -c:a aac -b:a 96k -af "aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100,aresample=dither_method=triangular_hp:resampler=soxr" -vf "scale=1200:-1,setsar=1" -c:v av1_qsv -global_quality 36 "<<OutputFileName>>"
```

This encoding fails due to `-vf "scale=1200:-1,setsar=1"` with the error:

> Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter
> 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0' Error
> reinitializing filters! Failed to inject frame into filter network:
> Function not implemented Error while processing the decoded data for
> stream #0:0

I was able to exactly use this code(I think, I definitely was able to scale before as I converted a lot of files before and wanted to scale them down... then I tried again and I think I used the same command line but maybe not. Anyway, I can convert fine if I do not add  `-vf "scale=1200:-1,setsar=1"`.

Also, this does work if I do not use `av1_qsv` (but I remember using it before and it was all working fine). I use `av1` since it is about 2x faster than `vp9_qsv`.

I'm simply trying to scale down and re-encode a bunch of video files... all this is automated so that is why the cmd line looks the way it does. As I said, I did have it working then came to use it again then started giving me this error.

Any ideas why trying to scale is failing?

Comment: `scale` filter is executed in the CPU. Do you want the scale filter to be executed in the CPU or in the GPU?

Comment: @Rotem GPU Of course. I'm trying to transcode a bunch of video using my gfx card(qsv of course). It seems to all work fine except the scaling.

Comment: I added scale_qsv going off the scale_cuda analogy(scale_qsv is not sowing up in the docs) and it seemed to work but is about 1/2 as fast and is running at the same speed as others. I'm getting about 60% gpu and mediastream activity.

Comment: I think 60% gpu is normal. AV1 encoding (`av1_qsv` argument) is probably the most demanding part. Running 1/2 as fast compared to what?

Comment: @Rotem Compared to not scaling. I can't be 100% sure but I encoded a file that ran at 30x(800 or so fps) without the scale(as when I was trying to get it to work)... then runs at 20x(about 500 or so) with the scale(which was the only difference I was testing at the time but the test wasn't scientific so can't be 100% sure it's taking up "50%" on the scale.

Comment: What is the original resolution and what is the resolution after scaling? In case the scale reduces the performance, I don't know if there is anything we can do about it.

Comment: I get this issue, too, with `ffmpeg` 6.1.1 and Cuda 12.4.